# MD.get_running_app().root.ids are empty in android but on pc it runs fine

Tags: python, kivy, adb, kivymd

I am making one app using kivymd. The app runs fine onto computer with python compiler but after i upload on android using adb install, it crashes.I have checked the logcat also. Actuallly the root.ids is empty. I have no idea why. Here is a snip from my code as well as adb logcat log.

Code-

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.utils import platform
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog


class GPSHelper():
has_centered_map = False

    def run(self):
        # Get a reference to GpsBlinker, then call blink()
        a = MDApp.get_running_app()
        print(a)
        gps_blinker = MDApp.get_running_app().root.ids.home_screen.ids.mapview.ids.blinker
        # Start blinking the GpsBlinker
        gps_blinker.blink()
```

The log error in adb shows

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
12-04 14:35:55.595 26138 26205 I python  :    File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 961, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
12-04 14:35:55.595 26138 26205 I python  :  KeyError: 'home_screen'
12-04 14:35:55.595 26138 26205 I python  :
12-04 14:35:55.595 26138 26205 I python  :  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
12-04 14:35:55.596 26138 26205 I python  :
12-04 14:35:55.596 26138 26205 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
12-04 14:35:55.596 26138 26205 I python  :    File "/mnt/d/Self/Python-programs/GPS-Copy/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 18, in <module>
12-04 14:35:55.596 26138 26205 I python  :    File "/mnt/d/Self/Python-programs/GPS-Copy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/FlightGPS/armeabi-v7a/kivy/app.py", line 955, in run
12-04 14:35:55.597 26138 26205 I python  :    File "/mnt/d/Self/Python-programs/GPS-Copy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/FlightGPS/armeabi-v7a/kivy/app.py", line 950, in _run_prepare
12-04 14:35:55.597 26138 26205 I python  :    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 731, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
12-04 14:35:55.597 26138 26205 I python  :    File "/mnt/d/Self/Python-programs/GPS-Copy/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 16, in on_start
12-04 14:35:55.597 26138 26205 I python  :    File "/mnt/d/Self/Python-programs/GPS-Copy/.buildozer/android/app/gpshelper.py", line 13, in run
12-04 14:35:55.598 26138 26205 I python  :    File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 964, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
12-04 14:35:55.598 26138 26205 I python  :  AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'. Did you mean: '__setattr__'?
12-04 14:35:55.598 26138 26205 I python  : Python for android ended.```


The kv files look something like below
main.kv

#:include homescreen.kv

MDScreen:
    MDNavigationLayout :
        MDScreenManager :
            HomeScreen:
                id: home_screen
````

and homescreen.kv

```
#:import utils kivy.utils
#:include homemapview.kv

<HomeScreen>:
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        # Info Bar
        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            padding: '10dp'
            adaptive_height: True
            # size_hint: {.6, .1}

            MDLabel:
                text: 'Speed(km/hr) : '
                halign: 'left'
                valign: 'top'
                font_size: 20


            MDLabel:
                text: 'Location'
                halign: 'right'
                valign: 'top'
                font_size: 20

        FloatLayout:
            #  map screen
            HomeMapView:

                id: mapview

            # button  Bar
            MDBoxLayout:
                padding: '5dp'
                adaptive_height: True
                MDIconButton:
                    icon: 'crosshairs-gps'
```